# How to transform String with dd MMM yyyy format in Calendar object

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to transform a String with the format 02 MAY 2019 to a Calendar object.

So I wrote this code :

```
String currentDate = "02 MAY 2019"
Date dateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(currentDate)
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance()
c.setTime(dateFormatted)
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
String month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

However, I got this error :

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:
>   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02 MAY 2019"

Can you help me to fix it please ? Thanks.

Comment: Your pattern does not match the formatting of the date-`String`: `"02 MAY 2019"` has the pattern `"dd MMM yyyy"`, but you are trying to parse it with `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, which just does not fit. Try `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse(currentDate)`, that might work.

Comment: Where are the slashes `/` in your `currentDate`? `SimpleDateFormat ` has to exactly match the input date string. Your input have spaces instead of slashes and 3 letters for month instead of 2.

Comment: Oh I was thinking that String in `SimpleDateFormat()` must be the output format, not the input format ... I try. I thanks for your answer.

Comment: @deHaar @Amongalen even if I use pattern `dd MMM yyyy` I'm still facing to the same error.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *I was thinking that String in `SimpleDateFormat()` must be the output format.* No, the output from parsing is a `Date`, and a `Date` cannot have a format. So that would not have made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just using the pattern suggested by the first answer and myself in a comment seems not to be sufficient.

I just tried it myself and got the `DateTimeParseException`, too.

I finally found out some code that does what you want, but it seems to require a certain `Locale`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String currentDate = "02 MAY 2019";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .parseLenient()
                                .appendPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
                                // does not work without the Locale:
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH); 
    DateTimeFormatter dtfIso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(currentDate, dtf);
    System.out.println(d.format(dtfIso));
}
```

This results in the output

```
02/05/2019
```

> One obviously has to pay attention to the order of method calls when defining the `DateTimeFormatter` for (uncommon?) patterns like this. In addition, not providing a `Locale` or providing a different one than `Locale.ENGLISH` seems to cause a `DateTimeParseException`, I changed it to `Locale.getDefault()` (GER in my case) and the `Exception` got thrown, however with an interesting message, because with mine the error criticized the index 4, not 3, as before with you.

Answer (score 2):

If on Java 8, you can use below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Code:

```
String currentDate = "02 MAY 2019";
//case insenstive parsing
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("dd MMM yyyy").toFormatter();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(currentDate, formatter);
//get directly from LocalDate what was intended from Calendar
int dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
String month = date.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
System.out.printf("dayOfWeek %d and month %s", dayOfWeek, month);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answser. However, I'm facing to this error : `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02 MAY 2019' could not be parsed at index 3`